# Angular file upload method not allowed 405

Tags: angularjs, http-post

I am using nervgh/angular-file-upload to upload files.
Once I click the upload button I found this error in the console.

"405 (Method Not Allowed)"

I have tried Google around, this error is deal with the POST, PUT, GET, DELETE...

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This error most probably does not relate to nervgh/angular-file-upload, but rather to your API not accepting the method you are using to upload files (please have a look here for something sounding very similar to your problem): https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/issues/293). Could you please post the full API response to ensure help instead of educated guessing ;) ?

Comment: Thx for directing me!